# (NSObject, AnyObject) is not convertible to DictionaryIndex<NSObject, AnyObject>

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I was working on converting this delegate protocol function from an Objective-C tutorial, but ran into an error trying to access the values in a dictionary by using the subscript to return the value based on the key. I am not quite sure what the error here means. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the sign up request should be submitted to the server
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool {
  var informationComplete: Bool = true

  // Loop through all of the submitted data
  for key in info {
    var field: String = info[key] // Error occurs at this line on info
    if field.isEmpty {
      informationComplete = false
      break
    }
  }

  // Display an alert if a field was not completed
  if !informationComplete {
    let alertView: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Missing Information", message: "Please make sure all information is filled out!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "ok")
  }

  return informationComplete
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not post your declaration. But likely you can solve it with:

```
for (key, field) in info {
  if field.isEmpty {
    informationComplete = false
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code and the error did go away, though I had to change `if field.isEmpty` to `if field.isEmpty == nil` otherwise there was an error. So theoretically this will just cycle through each key-value pair and if one of them is missing it throws the error correct? That is what I was looking for

Comment: Yes. It's one nice language icing that you get key/value pairs with this short syntax.

Comment: Okay thanks! I accepted your answer and after looking at it again I remember seeing something like this in the Swift by Tutorials book I got for Christmas. Should have recognized that haha. Thanks again!

Comment: Takes some time to grab all the new things. Especially if the SourceKitService crashes every 2 minutes :-(

Comment: Agreed! And I thought they fixed that problem in the latest version of Xcode 6. Might want to check if there is an update!